# identify circular parent/child records

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am trying to identify (and then prevent in the future) parent/children records in List object(having parent and child ID as integer property of SampleItem class) from pointing back at themselves.
Below is the SampleItem Class and list of SampleItem object:

```
public class SampleItem
    {
        public int ChildId{ get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }       
    }

List<SampleItem> items= new List<SampleItem>  
{
    new SampleItem{ ParentId=Null, ChildId=1 },
    new SampleItem{ ParentId=1, ChildId=2 },  
    new SampleItem{ ParentId=2, ChildId=4 },  
    new SampleItem{ ParentId=4, ChildId=1 }  
};
```

When I go to expand out the parent/children relationships it looks like this :
    1--> 2 --> 4 --> 1 (again) --> 2 (again) --> 3 (again)...repeating...(1 is root/parent of all)

SampleItems list object is like a tree structure where circular reference is not allowed.

How to identify these circular relationships and how can I prevent them in c# code? I would really appreciate if some one can answer this question.

Comment: You could use a simple rule that `ChildId` always must be greater than `ParentId`

Comment: Would you consider reworking your approach so that instead of tracking integer IDs that you instead track references to the parent and child `SampleItem` objects?

Comment: its not neccessary that ChildId will always be greater than ParentID. It may happen that ChildID may less than ParentID. Here I want to check that is there any circular reference exist in parent/child records. SampleItems list object is like a tree structure where circular reference is not allowed. @JSteward

Comment: Seems like you are essentially checking for a cycle in a linked list. The normal approach for this would be to have two different pointers to your starting item, then increment the first one at a time, and the second two at a time. If the faster increment ever comes back null, no such cycle exists. If they are ever both the same node, then the cycle does exist.

Comment: @JonathonChase Could you please add the code sample for the approach that you explained? I would really appreciate. I believe your approach is the right solution for my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially determining if a linked list has a cycle. The normal approach to this is to increment through the list at two different speeds and see if the nodes are ever equal, or if the faster incrementing node has exhausted the list. Using a slight modification to your base class to allow for a `null` value,

```
public class SampleItem
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

The following quick and dirty implementation will determine if your collection has a cycle for a list of `SampleItem`. This does assume that relationships are one to one and in your example and not one to many, as that would need to cover the case for each potential child.

```
void Main()
{
    List<SampleItem> itemsWithCycle = new List<SampleItem>
    {
        new SampleItem{ ParentId=null, ChildId=1 },
        new SampleItem{ ParentId=1, ChildId=2 },
        new SampleItem{ ParentId=2, ChildId=4 },
        new SampleItem{ ParentId=4, ChildId=1 }
    };
    List<SampleItem> itemsWithoutCycle = new List<SampleItem>
    {
        new SampleItem{ ParentId=null, ChildId=1 },
        new SampleItem{ ParentId=1, ChildId=2 },
        new SampleItem{ ParentId=2, ChildId=4 },
        new SampleItem{ ParentId=4, ChildId=5 }
    };

    Console.WriteLine(HasCycle(itemsWithCycle)); // true
    Console.WriteLine(HasCycle(itemsWithoutCycle)); // false


    bool HasCycle(IEnumerable<SampleItem> items) {
        var slow = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ParentId == null);
        var fast = slow;

        while(fast != null) {
            fast = Next(Next(fast));
            slow = Next(slow);

            if(fast == slow && fast != null) return true;
        }
        return false;

        SampleItem Next(SampleItem item)
        {
            if(item == null) return null;

            return items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ParentId == item.ChildId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There can be one to many. I mean one parent can have many children.in that case do I have to do any extra step?@JonathonChase